# Samsung Galaxy Note keyboard software

Tags: keyboard, samsung-galaxy-note, input-methods, notes, stylus

Is the software for the Galaxy Note keyboard (and its possibly its other unique features) available for other Android devices?

I am willing to pay and I also have a rooted phone, if that helps me get these features.

Specifically, as shown in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NJwhRnyYuyQ), at about 22 seconds in, there is an option to write with a stylus which gets automatically recognised as words, etc.

Comment: You mean the one where you just have to swipe over letters?

Comment: @RichardBorcsik I've updated the answer with a video demonstration of the Note keyboard.

Comment: in which device you want to use this feature?

Comment: @NISHANTRAJPUT I'd like it on all of my Android devices :) Specifically, Galaxy Nexus and Xoom.

Answer (score 4):

The "Graffiti" writing technology from the old PalmOS devices is available for Android now, and supports letter at a time text input with a stylus (or presumably a finger). [Graffiti for Android](https://www.appbrain.com/app/com.access_company.graffiti).

However, something like [DioPen](https://www.appbrain.com/app/com.diotek.ime.diopen) or [PenReader](https://www.appbrain.com/app/com.input.PenReaderStandard) seems to be more what you're after. They both have very mixed reviews, and do seem to be better on some devices than others, and take some getting used to.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know the stylus used with the Galaxy Note is special and works only with this particular device, so using that input method with different phones would mean to use the finger instead.

Having tried the handwriting recognition of the Note I found that it is not quite as good as it seemed on first glance and I went back to using "Graffiti for Android" which I had already been using for the Google Nexus One. On the Galaxy Note it also works with the stylus but the recognition rate using the finger is also quite good.

Comment: You are right, and the explanation is that Samsung notes include additional hardware, that is a screen layer with a digitizer where most android devices have only the touch screen layer. LG has also some devices with digitizer

Answer (score 0):

You can try google handwriting input.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.handwriting.ime&hl=en_IN

Comment: it's free too..